# Can Gstreamer be used server-side to stream audio to multiple clients on demand?

Tags: python, audio, stream, gstreamer

I'm working on an audio mixing program (DAW) web app, and considering using Python and Python Gstreamer for the backend.  I understand that I can contain the audio tracks of a single music project in a gst.Pipeline bin, but playback also appears to be controlled by this Pipeline.

Is it possible to create several "views" into the Pipeline representing the project?  So that more than one client can grab an audio stream of this Pipeline at will, with the ability to do time seek?

If there is a better platform/library out there to use, I'd appreciate advice on that too.  I'd prefer sticking to Python though, because my team members are already researching Python for other parts of this project.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Okay, I've been doing more looking around and I am beginning to think that there is no existing library that allows concurrent reads on some kind of audio project data structure that isn't rendered yet.  I hope I'm wrong...

Comment: What do you want to happen when any client does seek? Should it seek in exactly the same way for all clients ? What latency are you looking at ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at Flumotion (www.flumotion.org). It is a python based streaming server using GStreamer, you might be able to get implementation ideas from that in terms of how you do your application. It relies heavily on the python library Twisted for its network handling.